# How to print just a single integer inside a for loop not the entire array's result in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

This is the problem that I'm trying to solve:

> Given a number n followed by n numbers print the number which is greater than 15 if no number exists print -1.
>
> Input Description:
> 0<n<100 Given a number n Followed by n number in next line
>
> Output Description:
> Print the number which is greater than 15 if no number exsits print -1
>
> Sample Input :
>
> ```
> 3
> 5 7 4
> ```
>
> Sample Output :
>
> ```
> -1
> ```

I am trying to solve it like this:

```js
var n = 3
var nums = [5, 7, 4]
for (var i of nums){
    if (i > 15) {
        console.log(i)
     } else{
        console.log(-1)
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this output:

```
-1
-1
24
```

I want to just print `24` or `-1` if there is no number greater than `15`, may I please get a step-by-step explanation on this?

Comment: there already have answers, I just want to suggest you should use `let` instead of `var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for each number using the for loop and just use the `break` statement once you find that the situation is satisfied.

```js
 var n = 3
 var nums = [5, 7, 4, 24]
 // Let the end answer be -1
 let result = -1
 for (var i of nums) {
   if (i > 15) {
     // If the situation is satisfied, set the result and end the for loop.
     result = i
     break;
   } else {
     result = -1
   }
 }
 // At the end log the answer.
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Yeah also assuming the student didn't have access to using `break;`

Answer (score 0):

What you are running inside the `for` loop is run as many times as the for loop runs as a whole. Since this is a [homework answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) I am not going to give you a direct answer but think about what your code is doing now, your `if` block is running each time the for loop runs.

Some hints:

1. How many times does the for loop run?
2. Given that answer, how do you normally run something one time?
3. How could you do work in the loop then carry that work outside of the loop?
4. Remember your boolean operators. How do you keep something `true` once it is initially `false` and `true` after a condition is met?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for this. If you use a loop, return a found value instantly, or -1 if nothing is found (after the loop has completed). See snippet for both solutions.

```js
const n = 3;
const nums = [5, 7, 4];
const findValueInArrayGreaterThen = (arr, value) => arr.find(v => v > 15) || -1;

nums.unshift(3); // a number n followed by n numbers...

console.log(`nums: ${JSON.stringify(nums)}; findValueInArrayGreaterThen(nums, 15): ${
  findValueInArrayGreaterThen(nums, 15)}`);

nums.push(15.1);
console.log(`nums: ${JSON.stringify(nums)}; findValueInArrayGreaterThen(nums, 15): ${
  findValueInArrayGreaterThen(nums, 15)}`);

nums.pop();
console.log(`nums: ${JSON.stringify(nums)}; findValueInArrayGreaterThenLoop(nums, 15): ${
  findValueInArrayGreaterThenLoop(nums, 15)}`);

function findValueInArrayGreaterThenLoop(arr, value) {
  for (let value of nums) {
    if (value > 15) {
      return value;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```